# Does use of the Nest API require that the devices are all connected to the external Internet

Tags: remote-access, nest-api

Can a devices inside of a home communicate with one another using the Nest API without being connected to the external Internet, or does it require traffic to go through a cloud server?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the Nest API is a cloud API, the communication is through a server at wss://developer-api.nest.com

See the [Nest API Intro](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/nest-api-intro).